# Figuras huecas Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

solo necesito saber como podria volver estas dos figuras (triangulo y rombo) en unas figuras huecas, o sea , que solo se muestre sus bordes.
mi codigo es este:

```
def Rombo(n):

    l = [[' ' for x in range(n)] for z in range(n/2+1)]
    for e in range(n):
        for i in range(e,n-e):
            l[e][i] = '*'
    l = l[:0:-1]+l
    for i in l:
        print ' '.join(i)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
def triangulo():
   for i in range(5):
      for j in range(i+1):
         print "4",
      print

#---------------------------------------------
def imprimirRombo(n):

   n = n//2
   for i in range(n,0,-1):
       for j in range(n,(n-(i+1)),-1):
           print ' ',
       for k in range(i+1,n+1):
           print '*',
       print
   for i in range(0,n):
      for j in range(n,(n-(i+1)),-1):
          print ' ',
      for k in range(i+1,n+1):
         print '*',
      print 

#------------------------------------------------------------ 
def Cuadrado(largo,ancho):

   for i in range(largo):
       if i in[0]:
           print("* "*(ancho))
       elif i in[(largo-1)]:
           print("* "*(ancho))
       else:
           print("*"+"*"*(ancho)+" *")
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
def Pintar_CuadradoG(largo,ancho):

   for i in range(largo):
       if i in[0]:
          print("* "*(ancho))
       elif i in[(largo-1)]:
          print("* "*(ancho))
       else:
          print("*"+"  "*(ancho)+" *")
#------------------------------------------------------------           
def Pintar_CuadradoP(largo,ancho):
   for i in range(largo):
      if i in[0]:
         print(" * "*(ancho+2))
      elif i in[(largo-1)]:
         print(" * "*(ancho+2))
      else:
         print(" * "+" 1 "*(ancho)+" * ")

#------------------------------------------------------------ 
def Opciones():
  op=0
  while op!=1 and op!=2 and op!=3 and op!=9:
     print
     print " Menu de opciones"
     print"-----------------------"
     print "[1] Rombo"
     print "[2] Cuadrado"
     print "[3] Rombo "
     print "[9] terminar la ejecucion"
     op = int(raw_input("ingrese opcion: "))
  return op  

#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#programa
opcion=Opciones()
while opcion!=9:
    if opcion==1:
       Rombo(21)
       input()
    elif opcion==2:
       print
       Cuadrado(6,6)
       print
       print
       print "|Colores|"
       print"-------------------------------------------"
       print"Rojo =1 , Amarillo=2, Morado = 3"
       print"-------------------------------------------"
       print"Seleccione el color y tamaño que desea: "
       print"1)Rojo-Grande"
       print"2)Amarillo-Grande"
       print"3)Morado-Grande"
       print"4)Rojo-Pequeño"
       print"5)Amarillo-Pequeño"
       print"6)Morado-Pequeño"
       eleccion=int(raw_input("Ingrese su decision: "))
       if eleccion ==1:
          Pintar_CuadradoG(10,10)
          input()
       elif eleccion == 2:
          Pintar_CuadradoG(10,10)
          input()
       elif eleccion == 3:
          Pintar_CuadradoG(10,10)
          input()
       elif eleccion == 4:
          Pintar_CuadradoP(4,4)
          input()
       elif eleccion == 5:
          Pintar_CuadradoP(4,4)
          input()
       elif eleccion == 6:
          Pintar_CuadradoP(4,4)
          input()
       else:
          print"Debe ingresar un numero valido en el menu"
    elif opcion ==3: 
       imprimirRombo(12)
       print
       print
       print "|Colores|"
       print"-------------------------------------------"
       print"Rojo =1 , Amarillo=2, Morado = 3"
       print"-------------------------------------------"
       print"Seleccione el color y tamaño que desea: "
       print"1)Rojo-Grande"
       print"2)Amarillo-Grande"
       print"3)Morado-Grande"
       print"4)Rojo-Pequeño"
       print"5)Amarillo-Pequeño"
       print"6)Morado-Pequeño"
       decision=int(raw_input("Ingrese su decision: "))
        if decision ==1:
          imprimirRombo(12)
          input()
        elif decision ==2:
          triangulo()
          input()
    else:
      print"Debe ingresar una opcion valida"
print 'Adios, nos vemos :3'
```

Originalmente se muestran asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevo: Estoy consiguiendo en el caso del rombo pero me queda asi... ayuda :(

```
 def imprimirRombo(n):
    espacio = n-1
    for x in xrange(1,n):
       for y in xrange(1,espacio):
           print ' ',
       print '*'  
       for z in xrange(2,2*x-2):
           print ' ',
       if (x > 1):           
           print '*'
       espacio = espacio -1
    espacio=1
    for x in xrange(1,n-1):
       for y in xrange(1,espacio):
           print ' ',
       print '*'   
       for z in xrange(2,2*(n-x)-2):
           print ' ',
       if (x < n-1):    
           print '*'
       espacio = espacio+1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por algún motivo, intuyo que esas funciones tuyas asumen que todos los caracteres serán igual de anchos (para asegurarte de eso, deberías usar una fuente de anchura fija). Si pretendes hacer ASCII art con figuritas, mejor asegúrate de usar fuentes de anchura fija o te volverás loco intentándolo ; -)

Comment: Lo digo porque, si la anchura es variable, el posicionamiento en cuadrícula de los caracteres puede volverse tremendamente impredecible,  hacerlos encajar en dos dimensiones con anchura variable es una pesadilla poco práctica...

Comment: Solo los cambiare para mostrar figuras de diferentes tamaños, pero no mucho ,por lo mismo de que es complicado u.u ... asumiendo de que es fijo como recomendarias hacerlo? tengo la mitad de los bordes del rombo

Comment: Cuando digo "anchura fija" no me refiero a las figuras (está bien pensado lo de las funciones que pinten figuritas de tamaño dinámico). **Me refiero a la fuente de texto que muestra el resultado!**. Si un espacio es igual de ancho que cualquier caracter, lo que intentas se puede lograr con lógica simple y robusta.

Comment: lo he resuelto. De todas formas, no sé si esto son deberes de colegio o un proyecto personal tuyo, pero le veo bastantes fallos al programita en general. Aparte de las opciones del menú que fallan, creo que el código se podría estructurar mejor. **Recomiendo que, tras aplicar la solución de mi respuesta, intentes** [refactorizar el código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactorizaci%C3%B3n) **antes de añadir o modificar las características de su comportamiento**, para facilitarte a tí mismo modificarlo después. La idea es hacer la estructura del código más flexible.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a leer, es un proyecto personal bueno.. tampoco proyecto es para entender mejor este lenguaje, ya que me cuesta mucho esto de las figuras y backtracking. De verdad te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He arreglado el triángulo y el rombo:

Modifica la función `triangulo` así:

```
def triangulo():
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if (j in[0,i] or i == 4):
                print "4",
            else:
                print " ",
        print
```

Para el Rombo:

```
def Rombo(n):
    l = [[' ' for x in range(n)] for z in range(n/2+1)]
    for e in range(n):
        for i in range(e,n-e):
            if (i in [e, n-e-1]):
                l[e][i] = '*'
    l = l[:0:-1]+l
    for i in l:
        print ' '.join(i)
```

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!! me haz ayudado mucho con esto, enserio te lo agradezco mucho!!! ... una ultima pregunta, como puedo aplicar backtracking en  alguna de estas funciones? he estado leyendo sobre eso pero mis intentos explotan XD muchas gracias de nuevo y disculpa todas las molestias u.u

Comment: @Wolf es la primera vez que oigo eso del `backtracing`. Lo he buscado, y parece ser un patrón que usa funciones [recursivas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n) de una forma muy específica. Talvez valdría la pena dedicarle una pregunta propia al tema del `backtracing`, ya que se sale del contexto de esta pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, lo pienso hacer. Es mejor que nunca la tengas que usar , esa cosa es del diablo XD jajaaj

Comment: Para entender el backtracing, creo que deberías comprender la forma de crear [funciones recursivas](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2774-funciones-recursivas-en-python/). Las funciones recursivas son una alternativa a los clásicos bucles tipo `for`, `foreach` y `while`. En vez de crear un bloque cíclico, usas una función que se llama a sí misma hasta llegar a la solución base (esto a veces tiene ventajas que los clásicos bucles no tienen). En los ejemplos del enlace incluido en este comentario verás claro cómo es una función recursiva.