# Problemas menu Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

mi menu tiene muchos errores y quisiera saber en que me estoy equivocando.
Uno de los problemas es que no me deja salir del programa si presiono 4 , otro es que si elijo una opcion me muestra la figura que deseo pero despues no se como hacer para volver al menu principal si el usuario desea seguir preguntando... en cambio me aparece este error

Pienso que aqui esta el error, no lo se:

```
#programa
opcion=Opciones()
while True:
#------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#Si el usuario quiere pintar un cuadrado se le da multiples opciones   
if opcion == 1:
    print
    Cuadrado(6,6)
    eleccion=Menu_Colores()
    if eleccion == 1:
        Pintar_CuadradoG1(13,13)
        input()
    elif eleccion == 2:
        Pintar_CuadradoG2(13,13)
        input()
    elif eleccion == 3:
        Pintar_CuadradoG3(13,13)
        input()
    elif eleccion == 4:
        Pintar_CuadradoP1(4,4)
        input()
    elif eleccion == 5:
        Pintar_CuadradoP2(4,4)
        input()
    elif eleccion == 6:
        Pintar_CuadradoP3(4,4)
        input()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#Si el usuario quiere pintar un triangulo se le da multiples opciones             
elif opcion == 2: 
        Triangulo()
        seleccion = Menu_Colores()
        if seleccion == 1:
            Pintar_TriG1()
            input()
        elif seleccion == 2:
            Pintar_TriG2()
            input()
        elif seleccion == 3:
            Pintar_TriG3()
            input()
        elif seleccion == 4:
            Pintar_TriP1()
            input()
        elif seleccion == 5:
            Pintar_TriP2()
            input()
        elif seleccion == 6:
            Pintar_TriP3()
            input()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#Si el usuario quiere pintar un rombo se le da multiples opciones             
elif opcion == 3:
    Rombo(7)
    decision = Menu_Colores()
    if decision == 1:
        Pintar_RomboG1(13)
        input()
    elif decision == 2:
        Pintar_RomboG2(13)
        input()
    elif decision == 3:
        Pintar_RomboG3(13)
        input()
    elif decision == 4:
        Pintar_RomboP1(7)
        input()
    elif decision == 5:
        Pintar_RomboP2(7)
        input()
    elif decision == 6:
        Pintar_RomboP3(7)
        input()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#Si el usuario ingresa una opcion no valida        
else:
    print"Debe ingresar una opcion valida"
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
  opcion=Opciones()        
print 'Adios, nos vemos :3'
```

Comment: La idea de compartir el código es para que podamos copiarlo y testearlo nosotros mismos. Si lo que haces es subir una foto, no podemos copiarlo. Por favor elimina las fotos y pega el código como texto identado. Además, por favor pega solo las partes que te dan problema, no todo el programa.

Comment: perdon, es muy largo y no tengo idea de donde esta el problema asi que por eso lo puse todo pero ya lo arregle.

Comment: Esos `input()` para qué están? Lo lógico es que sean asignados a una variable. No se ve cómo será el resto del código, pero por ejemplo `opcion = int(input("Escriba un nº de opción"))`. Así si se tipea `"4"` (str) `opcion` se establecerá como `4` (int) y en el siguiente ciclo se imprimirá `"Debe ingresar una opción válida"`

Comment: El código de esta pregunta está relacionado con el que sale en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225347/3436). En ambas preguntas, está implicado el mismo script.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, creo que la función `Opciones` también está implicada, la escribiste así si no la has modificado:

```
def Opciones():
    op=0
    while op!=1 and op!=2 and op!=3 and op!=9:
        print
        print " Menu de opciones"
        print"-----------------------"
        print "[1] Rombo"
        print "[2] Cuadrado"
        print "[3] Rombo "
        print "[9] terminar la ejecucion"
        op = int(raw_input("ingrese opcion: "))
    return op
```

**Dicho esto**, yo creo que la solución pasa por reestructurar el código. Todas esas llamadas a `input()` sin parámetros podrían reemplazarse por algo que sirva de verdad. Por ejemplo, esta línea:

```
opcion=Opciones()
```

Reemplazando todos esos `input()` vacíos y sin asignar por `opcion=Opciones()`, al menos el menú se vuelve más fluido, reinvocando el menú principal tras pintar una figurita. Aún tiene pequeños fallitos, pero sólo con esto ya mejora mucho.

---

### Información complementaria

**Pero OJO!** No puedo ignorar que esto añade más [código duplicado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_duplicado) a la mezcla. Si el código de tu programita se adhiriese más al principio DRY (*Don't Repeat Yourself*, o *No Te Repitas* en Español), te resultará más fácil mantener el código en el futuro (añadir modificaciones, arreglar fallos, etc.). Para solucionarlo, habría que refactorizar. Ahora que, no es fácil decidir cómo hacer esa refactorización.

[Esta sección de refactoring.guru (en inglés)](https://refactoring.guru/smells/duplicate-code) explica en detalle sobre los problemas que puede dar el código duplicado, y cómo evitarlo. Te recomiendo fuertemente echar un vistazo a las páginas [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru) y [sourcemaking.com](https://sourcemaking.com). Ambas contienen información muy completa (en inglés, pero muy buena) sobre técnicas de refactorización, así como patrones de diseño y cómo aplicarlos, además de antipatrones, "olores" del código y cómo contrarrestarlos, etc. La información mostrada en ellas es válida para múltiples lenguajes de programación, y es de gran ayuda para aprender el Arte del Código Limpio.

Tras ver eso, deberías juzgar tú mismo cómo prefieres reestructurar tu código, creo yo. Pero, por decir algo, a lo mejor sería beneficioso para ti que te reemplazaras los [números mágicos por constantes simbólicas](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-magic-number-with-symbolic-constant); favorecería un código más obvio a los ojos de un humano. Aunque, incluso con el uso de constantes simbólicas, se "huele" cierta [obsesión por los tipos primitivos](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

**Tampoco hace falta que te pongas a refactorizar como loco!** Pero creo que sería bueno para ti considerar toda esa información.